# Where do I find the three thunderstorm shout  words?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been wondering which is the best shout and recently concluded that it was thunderstorm. I sadly only know the location of the first word of power.

Where are the other two remaining words of the thunderstorm shout located?

Comment: There is no location for the "first word". There are three locations for the three words, and whichever you find first will have the first word.

Answer (score 3):

A list of Shouts, including the [Storm Call](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Call) shout, can be found [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_shouts#Dragon_Shouts).  Click on the shout to find locations for each one.

The three words are located in [Forelhost](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Forelhost), [High Gate Ruins](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/High_Gate_Ruins), and [Skuldafn](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Skuldafn).

Comment: While its nice to have a more general source, it would also be good to copy the specific information that answers the question, in case the link goes bad.